# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException When consume WCF web service with java client using apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wcf, cxf

I have a simple wcf in website hosted on iis and I try to call it from java client web application on

wildfly 10
I used apache cxf to implement web service client as below :

```
@WebServiceClient
(name="BankService",targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",
wsdlLocation="http://khalil/BankService-15-7-2016/Service.svc?wsdl")
public class BankService  extends Service
{
    private final static URL BANKSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException BANKSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName BANKSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BankService");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://khalil/BankService-15-7-2016/Service.svc?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        BANKSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        BANKSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
    public BankService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), BANKSERVICE_QNAME);
    }
    public BankService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), BANKSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }
    public BankService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, BANKSERVICE_QNAME);
    }
    public BankService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, BANKSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }
    public BankService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public BankService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }
    @WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_IBankService")
    public IBankService getWSHttpBindingIBankService() {
        return super.getPort(new QNam("http://tempuri.org/","WSHttpBinding_IBankService"),IBankService.class);
    }
    @WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_IBankService")
    public IBankService getWSHttpBindingIBankService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "WSHttpBinding_IBankService"), 

IBankService.class, features);
    }
    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (BANKSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw BANKSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return BANKSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }
}
```

and I call ws operation as below :

```
 BankService bank_service = new BankService();
IBankService bank_port = bank_service.getWSHttpBindingIBankService();
double b = bank_port.getBalance(123456L);
```

and this exeption is thrown :

```
12:55:15,226 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21) An error occurred in trying to obtain a TGT: Invalid null input: 

name

12:55:15,227 SEVERE [com.controller.DSMCEcontroller] (default task-21) null: 

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error occurred in trying to obtain a TGT: Invalid null input: name
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.getBalance(Unknown Source)
    at com.controller.DSMCEcontroller.PurchaceOrder(DSMCEcontroller.java:83)
    at com.controller.RegisterController.prepareCreate(RegisterController.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction

(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest

(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest

(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest

(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest

(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest

(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest

(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest

(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest

(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest

(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest

(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest

(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest

(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest

(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In IIS manager I set anonymous authentication to enable but same result
also I try to provide username and passowrd in client application like that

```
BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "ComputerName\\MyUSERNAME");
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "MYPASSWORD");
```

also not work .

Can anyone help me with it please?

Comment: 'An error occurred in trying to obtain a TGT: Invalid null input: name' seems a server error, so it is not an authentication problem. What are your server logs writing?

Comment: the exception above is from wildfly log

Comment: I mean the log of the JAX-WS server, which has generated the SoapFault